# Is it ok to use Islamic donations as tax deductibles?

Tags: zakat, sadaqah, finance

Every year I see many masjids and Islamic organizations requesting for funds. They also state the donations are tax deductible.

Hence, my question is: is this permissible? Is there not a fear that some people will give money to save on tax and not really for the Akhirah?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is called " Al neya" or the intention. That situation you describe will be bad for the Muslim who do it, but not further. He will not receive "Al thawab" in Alakhira, but the action is valid for the community, e.g the mosque or a poor guy can accept that "Sadakat" or donnations .

Comment: IMO this doesn't answer the question fully. My dear brother SE is unlike the usual internet forums a place where we want full, focused, good researched and helpful answers supported by evidences, just giving answers which are more likely comments doesn't fit at all to this model. Please consider taking our [tour] and check the [help] to learn more how SE works or should work!